# Initiate the Javascript for Material Design WEB

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design

I am using Material Design WEB components.

Added the below css and js

```
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

On separate JS file I have tried

```
const textField = document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field');
mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(textField);

const button = document.querySelector(".mdc-button");
mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(button);

const formField = document.querySelector('.mdc-form-field');
const checkbox = document.querySelector('.mdc-checkbox');
mdc.formField.input= checkbox;
```

If I have the two textbox in the HTML is works for only only first element, doesn't work for other. Checkbox is not at all working.

```
<label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
                    <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" asp-for="Username" autofocus aria-labelledby="user name">
                    <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
                        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
                        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                            <span class="mdc-floating-label" asp-for="Username">User Name</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>


<label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined">
                    <input type="password" class="mdc-text-field__input" asp-for="Password" aria-labelledby="password">
                    <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
                        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
                        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
                            <span class="mdc-floating-label" asp-for="Password" autocomplete="off">Password</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
```

[image]

Where can I find the list of instantiating JavaScript something like this :

```
mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(document.querySelector('.foo-button'));
```

Comment: Can you attach a code snippet instead which we could run?

Answer (score 0):

Attaching the **data-mdc-auto-init** to the root element works for me.

```
<button class="mdc-icon-button" 
   aria-label="Add to favorites"
   aria-pressed="false"
   data-mdc-auto-init="MDCIconButtonToggle">
  <i class="material-icons mdc-icon-button__icon mdc-icon-button__icon--on">favorite</i>
  <i class="material-icons mdc-icon-button__icon">favorite_border</i>
</button>
```

At the bottom of the page

```
<script>mdc.autoInit()</script>
```

Reference https://material.io/develop/web/components/auto-init/